# Spring Boot returns Error 404 even though mapping has been set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I downloaded a Spring Boot project from Spring Initializr. I am trying to call `sayHello()` method in DemoApplication.java. Here are my code.

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("started");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Success");
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "myName", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run on http://localhost:8080/hello it returns error 404 page. It does not call `sayHello()` method even though I have set the GET mapping. What could be the issue?

Comment: Clear up your dependencies… use `spring-boot-starter-web` as the only dependency.

Comment: I do not recall ever having seen both `@Configuration` (as part of `@SpringBootApplication`) and an `@Controller` annotation on the same class. I recommend splitting them into separate classes.

Comment: Remove the `spring-web` dependency and replace with `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok ```spring-web``` dependency is the culprit. Thank you. Also thanks to @slauth

Comment: It isn't so-much `spring-web` but the missing of `spring-webmvc` which is automatically included in `spring-boot-starter-web`. Those starters exists for the reason that you don't have to hunt dependencies yourself (also jackson would be missing here and some others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your dependencies, or rather the lack of them.

You included `spring-web` as a dependency but that isn't enough to launch your web app. You would also need to add `spring-webmvc` and as you want to use REST (and probably JSON) you would need to add the `jackson-databind` dependency (and if you want to support dates also the `jackson-datatype-jdk8` dependency).

Now you could of course manually figure all this out yourself by trial and error. Or you just include the `spring-boot-starter-web` which automatically includes (compatible) versions of all of those dependencies (including Embedded Tomcat).

So in short fix your dependencies.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This should be all you need, if you build a WAR instead of JAR you might want to add

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will make tomcat provided and moved out of the lib folder but still your app would be runnable for development (through the `main` method) and deployable as a war (without tomcat being in the lib directory).